# Ford Mondeo 2006 TDCI won't start

Tags: ford, cranks-wont-run, mondeo, tdci

First of all I am new to the forum world but I have reached a dead end and would welcome any new input.

My Mondeo was driving perfectly when suddenly and without any warning symptoms the engine cut out and will not start. I am not new to working on cars and have a fully equiped workshop but after two days I have achieved nothing.  I should also add that I have two identical cars and the other one is running.  So far I have:

- Checked that there is fuel at the rail.
- Checked that all injectors are receiving fuel
- Checked that fuel flows freely from the filter which is fairly new
- Checked that the fuel pressure regulator on the pump is working
- Swapped over all relays from the running car
- Swapped over the flywheel sensor from the running car.
- Checked the fuel output from both high pressure pumps.  They were identical.
- This car does not have a second low pressure delivery pump.
- The glow plugs are working.
- The running car has four new injectors and my next text will be to put these in the non running car.  I have never heard of all four injectors failing at exactly the same time !!!!!!!
- If I squirt start pilot into the inlet it fires.

My gut feeling is that it is an electrical failure preventing the injectors from firing - but what?

I have diagnostic equipment which cam up with:

- P2288 injector pressure above expected level
- P0251 injector pump fuel metering control malfunction

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. I'm an English guy living in Krautland.